# Geometry Nodes: How the nearest face/edge is found?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created a cube, aligned with axes, going from world origin to 1;1;5, and moved vertex 0 to the nearest face:

[image] [image] [image]

The vertex moved to the center of the nearest face, described by vertices 0154. It moved $\sqrt{0.5^2 + 2.5^2} = 2.55...$.

If it instead moved to the center of the face described by vertices 0462, it would move much less, $\sqrt{0.5^2 + 0.5^2} = 0.707...$.

Apparently my understanding, that the nearest face is the face with the nearest center was wrong. But then **what makes a face the nearest face?**

Comment: I guess you have applied the scale of the cube so that this is not the issue? Because if it was just a cube scaled on the Z axis, then I wouldn't even know what center should be preferred by this, as the centers of 0154, 0132 and 0264 would all be the same distance away.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the scale is applied, let me upload the file... Uploaded.

Comment: just a guess: the nearest vertex? or the average of all vertices distances?

Comment: Face that has nearest point. you have 3 since 0 nearest itself. so real q: how break tie. prob random.

Comment: @Chris the description says "using face and edge centers for distance computation"

Comment: For me [it's working as expected](https://imgur.com/a/HOnTjnT): nearest face-centre before transformation

Comment: @RobinBetts Have you tested in Blender 3.0? Look at my answer to see how it works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Crantisz I think I finally understand:

The nearest face is the face built on an edge that is the nearest to the *Source Position*.

- **not** a face with the nearest center to s.p.
- **not** a face with the nearest vertex to s.p.
- **not** a face that could have a point on its surface closer to the s.p. than any possible point on any other face.

**But what is the nearest edge then?**

The nearest edge is an edge, on which you could place a point closer to the s.p. than any point you could place on any other edge.

- **not** an edge with the nearest center to s.p.
- **not** an edge with the nearest vertex to s.p.

Below I spawn an icosphere on the nearest edge to vertex #0:

[image]

Below I spawn an icosphere on the nearest face to vertex #0 (I positioned vert #0 to lay on the surface of the big face):

[image]

Now I stretch and move the small face along X, so neither its vertices nor centers of its edges are closer to s.p. than the top vertex (#2) of the big face) - and yet it still spawns the icosphere, because the top and bottom edges come closer to vert #0 than any other edge:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think transfer attribute works in a slightly different way - it gets face nearest to face. This works only when you try to transfer data from face to face. I don't know how it works under the hood then you use vertexes instead of faces, but from my point of view, it doesn't have any sense. So I decided to convert face to points and then try to find the closest.

Now it works as expected:

[image]

UPD.

A, gotcha!

Look at this example:

[image]

Then you use faces as point, Blender gets the middle from faces connected to point. As you see this middle point much closer to one of the long faces

Comment: The update doesn't make sense though  Capture attribute is redundant there, and I don't get the explanation. But "Mesh to Points" as you used it in the first part is exactly what I should use to find the center of a face nearest by its center.